Mosquitto MQTT-Broker (Bridge) stops storing messages in persistence after a while when disconnected
I'm running 2 Systems:

one has the Publisher (sends data every 10 seconds) and a mosquitto-broker configured as a bridge.

The other system has the main mosquitto-broker and the subscriber-client that writes the messages into a database.


The first system is eventually deployed out in the field connected via mobile network and I need it to store messages if the network is down.
When everything is connected it all works fine but when the second system is disconnected (simulating a system downtime) the broker on the first system stores the sent messages in the persistence database for some time, then stops. The duration of storing is reproducable.
In the logs of the first broker I can see the error "Error creating bridge: Broken pipe." and after this no more messages are stored in persistence.
If the second system is connected again the messages that were stored are sent to it.
I am running mosquitto version 1.5.7 and my mosquitto-config of the bridge is:
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

connection OT-to-IT
address 192.168.10.244
cleansession false
bridge_insecure true
remote_password <password>
remote_username <user>
remote_clientid <client_id>

try_private true
topic # both 1

autosave_interval 10
persistent_client_expiration 30d
max_queued_messages 0
max_queued_bytes 0
#keepalive_interval 65535
keepalive_interval 0

I tried playing around with the keepalive_interval and that changes the delay of said error-message and therefore the messages are written to persistence for longer or shorter.
If I set the keepalive_interval to 65535 (max) I get about half an hour of stored messages. I however need at least 3-4 days.
If I set the keepalive_interval 0 it should be disabled but I get the error after not even a minute and only 4 messages are stored.
I'd really appreciate if someone knew a solution to this.
Thanks in advance :D

Why are you deploying new services with mosquitto 1.5.7? The mosquitto 2.0.x has been available for a long time now.

@hardillb Because according to apt that's the newest available version... Currently trying some things to get it to update...
